# GLSL normal colors

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, normals

I'm trying to draw my models normals as colors with GLSL. I tried:

```
// 'normal' come from VBO and v_normal is sent to the fragment shader
v_normalColor = normal;
```

But the color is not like normal maps I can see on the web.
Do you have any idea how to calculate this ?

EDIT: Here is what I used :  `v_normalColor = normal * 0.5f + 0.5f;`

Simply :)

Comment: Remember that colors usually fill the range `[0,1]` (unless using HDR), whereas normals usually fill the range `[-1,1]`, assuming your calculations for the model normals are correct. So you almost certainly need to transform the normal values in some way to make sure that their full range maps to the full range of the color spectrum that your resulting image allows.

Comment: try `v_normalColor = (normalize(normal) * 0.5f ) + 0.5f;` also may be image would tell us more what is going on ... do you have other passes perhaps?

Comment: It works with this line, I edited my post yesterday, but thank you very much ! :)